# Listview Icons not displaying

Tags: vb.net

I'm having a difficulties in displaying the icons in the listview.
I tried this code but nothing happens.

```
Dim imageList1 As ImageList
    imageList1 = New ImageList()
    imageList1.Images.Add(Bitmap.FromFile("C:\Users\Documents\Visual Studio 2012\Projects\MYPS\MYPSApp (client-local.vbp)\Images\UserListview.ico"))
    mvarListView.SmallImageList = imageList1
```

Actually, I don't want the code above, because it is really hardcoded.
What I want is:
In my listview, there's a property there that is called "SmallImageList".
Clicking the collection of the images of that property gives me a 0-27 lists of images. (see image)

[Collection of Images in Designer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/d26q5.png)

What I want to display is the #27 icon at the left of my listview, how?

```
    Dim clmX As System.Windows.Forms.ColumnHeader
        Dim itmX As System.Windows.Forms.ListViewItem

mvarListView.View = System.Windows.Forms.View.Details

        mvarListView.MultiSelect = False
        mvarListView.GridLines = True
        mvarListView.LabelEdit = False

        mvarListView.Columns.Clear()
        mvarListView.Items.Clear()


itmX = mvarListView.Items.Add("")

            On Error Resume Next
            'UPGRADE_ISSUE: MSComctlLib.ListItem property itmX.SmallIcon was not upgraded. Click for more: 'ms-help://MS.VSCC.v90/dv_commoner/local/redirect.htm?keyword="CC4C7EC0-C903-48FC-ACCC-81861D12DA4A"'
            itmX.Selected = CShort(listnode.selectSingleNode("icon").nodeTypedValue)

            ' itmX.ImageKey = CShort(listnode.selectSingleNode("icon").nodeTypedValue)
            **itmX.ImageKey = 27**  '<-- not working :(

        itmX.Text = CStr(listnode.selectSingleNode("text").nodeTypedValue)
            itmX.Tag = listnode.selectSingleNode("type").nodeTypedValue

                       subitemnodes = listnode.selectNodes("subitem")
            For i = 1 To columncount - 1
                'UPGRADE_WARNING: Lower bound of collection itmX has changed from 1 to 0. Click for more: 'ms-help://MS.VSCC.v90/dv_commoner/local/redirect.htm?keyword="A3B628A0-A810-4AE2-BFA2-9E7A29EB9AD0"'
                If itmX.SubItems.Count > i Then
                    itmX.SubItems(i).Text = CStr(subitemnodes(i - 1).nodeTypedValue)
                Else

                    itmX.SubItems.Insert(i, New System.Windows.Forms.ListViewItem.ListViewSubItem(Nothing, CStr(subitemnodes(i - 1).nodeTypedValue)))
                End If
            Next
```

Please Help.

Thanks,
Yow

[No Icons](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zxwfX.png)

Comment: `itmX.ImageIndex = 27` hard to imagine you'd miss that in intellisense if you tried anything at all

Comment: what do you mean miss that intellisense? Here's the output, it didn't contain any icons in the left of my listview.. (see the image at the top)

Comment: [IntelliSense](http://i.imgur.com/VB9p1YG.jpg)

Comment: Yeah, I knew that... i just don't know how can I put icons in the listview. thats it.

Answer (score 0):

The credit for this really goes to Plutonix, as he suggested it in the comments, but here goes:

In your code you have this line that you're saying doesn't work:

```
itmX.ImageKey = 27
```

That doesn't work for a good reason: [ImageKey](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.listviewitem.imagekey(v=vs.110).aspx) sets the current image by the string key assigned to each image, not by its positional index. What you want to be using is [ImageIndex](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.listviewitem.imageindex(v=vs.110).aspx), like so:

```
itmX.ImageIndex = 27
```

Give that a try. If you're setting your `SmallImageList` property on the ListView to your image list, it should work.

Comment: Hi Sir Adrian, I tried "itmX.ImageIndex = 27" but it is still not working. Same output, no icons in the listview... any ideas why?

Comment: Even if I changed   'mvarListView.View = System.Windows.Forms.View.Details'  to
                'mvarListView.View = System.Windows.Forms.View.SmallIcon 'lcl 11/26/2015'

Comment: Have you tried any other indexes than 27? Like, say, 5, or 12, or 19?

Comment: Yes, i tried also the indexes 1-10, same output... Thanks for helping sir. Any suggestions?